# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) when running mysql -uroot

Tags: mysql

Out of the sudden, I am getting this error:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

on mysql when I run `mysql -uroot`.

I haven't touched web dev for around 1 month and as soon as I wanted to return to my project, I am getting this very annoying error out of nowhere. I have trie all advice and solutions from other answers and none of them work. This includes changing permissions to 777, ownership to root, mysql etc, killing PID all of those and none of them work. I even tried re-installing mysql and still getting the same error. I even re-installed my whole macOS Mojave and still getting the same error. I mean this error doesn't even make sense...

Is mysql completely broken or I am just super dumb?

Has anyone had this issue? If so how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error says, it's using the socket /tmp/mysql.sock and failed.

Try to troubleshoot with the below things.

1. check the process status of mysqld and confirm its running or not.  If running which socket is using.

`ps -ef | grep -i mysqld`

2. Based on the socket file try login to the MySQL through command line.

`mysql -uroot -p -S <<file.sock>>`

3. Check the `my.cnf` to make sure which socket file its mentioned under the [client] group option.
4. In your case, probably the mysql instance reading the socket from `my.cnf` files where it placed somewhere.  Check the hierarchy of the configuration file usage by mysqld which may be located in either the `/etc` or `/etc/mysql`